# Why am I obtaining "URI formats are not supported" exception trying to write into a log file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a method that take a string containing a message and write this string into a log file.

I have done in this way:

```
internal static void WriteLogFile(string messageLog)
{
    if (messageLog == "")
    {
        messageLog = "L'import delle regole di inoltro è andato a buon fine. Tutte le regole di inoltro sono state inserite";
    }

    try
    {
        var filePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("it-IT");

        File.WriteAllText(filePath + "log.txt", messageLog);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when perform this line:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath + "log.txt", messageLog);
```

I am obtaining the following exception:

```
"URI formats are not supported."
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: Don't use a URI in the first place. You already have a proper path, why use `new Uri` ?

Comment: Use `Location` rather than `GetName().CodeBase` to get a file path. If your assembly really was loaded from a URI, you'll have to make a decision as to where the log file should go -- it obviously can't go to the place where it came from.

Comment: how does `filepath` look like, when you try to use it?. The exception seems pretty clear. You are passing a URI in a format that is not supported.

Comment: Why your use an URI and not an absolute path?

Comment: You should probably use a logging library instead of creating your own. Deferred writing, localization, logging of diagnostic data like assemblies, type names etc are already implemented in Serilog, NLog, log4net etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because WriteAllText does not support a URI format, and you're using a URI.

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8, you need to pass it a string path.

As others have suggested, you should use GetPath if you want to create the file locally, or some other method depending where you want the file to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace YourNameSpace.Models
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private Object Locker { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public Logger(string path)
        {
            Locker = new Object();
            Path = path;
        }

        public void Log(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                string messageToLog = string.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now, string.Format(message, args));
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, string.Format("{0}.txt", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);
                File.AppendAllLines(path, new string[] { messageToLog });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Even if the OP asked `how can I log in my application` this wouldn't be a good answer

Comment: Well it does, a well written class is still better than a wrong written method, I guess

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - what's a valid path format. It's not appropriate for logging either - .NET itself already has a logging infrastructure through the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, but most people use libraries like Serilog, NLog and log4net. These libraries handle concurrency, caching, formatting and separate the act of logging from the logging provider. *This* class for example is prone to concurrency issues despite the `lock` statement

Comment: You mean concurrency on the file? Yes it is, but depends on the needs in my opinion

Comment: There's no reason to reinvent the wheel when the .NET Framework already provides this functionality (without threading issues) and a *lot* of third-party libraries provide even more powerful and easier to use alternatives

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your problem is to write a log file in the same folder as your executable. Try to use the [`Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location) property:

```
var filePath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

That will return a valid path that you can concatenate with the file name, or use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) method.